# Relink Error Using SQLPlus in Alpine Linux

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle12c, alpine-linux

- Oracle: 12.1.0.2.0
- Alpine: 3.7

I have Oracle and instantclient working already. The application works fine, queries run fine. There are some integration tests that use SQLPlus and I would like to get those working without changing too much.

When `sqlplus` runs I get the following error:

```
sqlplus: Relink `/lib/libkeyutils.so.1' with `/usr/glibc-compat/lib/libc.so.6' for IFUNC symbol `strrchr'
```

I have not programmed C in like 20 years, I have no idea what I need to do here...

Comment: Are you using SQL\*Plus from the Oracle server (and/or full client) installation, or from the instant client distribution? You might have both versions in your path, so check which you actually hit (with `which` or `whence` or similar, or by examining the path manually...)

Comment: I'm getting it from `instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip` so I assume that means the latter

Comment: Yeah it's the instant client distribution. The full client never even gets in this docker image. Dist lives under `/usr/lib/instant_client_12_1` which gets put in the path

Comment: OK, I assumed that the Oracle DB was running on the same machine, so was ruling out a clash with the server software or picking up the wrong thing. Seems it isn't that, and I can't replicate your environment, so I'll bow out. (You could try using [SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/downloads/index.html) instead of SQL\*Plus; you still shouldn't need to change anything in your scripts. That's a bit out of scope though.) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Someone at work was able to find a solution on the Google interwebs that works.

I added the following to our Dockerfile and now sqlplus is working.

```
RUN wget -O libkeyutils.tar.xz https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/keyutils/download/ \\
&& tar xvf libkeyutils.tar.xz -C /tmp \\
&& cp /tmp/usr/lib/libkeyutils.so.1.8 /usr/lib/instantclient_12_1/libkeyutils.so.1
```